# Passing keytab location programmatically is failing (Kafka / Kerberos)

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kerberos, keytab

I am trying to pass the value of keytab in my zookeeper-jass.conf file. 
I am retrieving it using the following code:

```
String baseDirectory = System.getProperty("user.dir");
baseDirectory = baseDirectory.replace("\\", "/");
String keyTabPath = baseDirectory + "/test.keytab";

java.io.FileInputStream fs = null;
Properties prop=prop =new Properties();
fs = new java.io.FileInputStream(loginConfigPath);
prop.load(fs);

String keyTab = (String) prop.get("keyTab");
String newKeyTabPath = "\""+keyTabPath+"\"";
prop.setProperty("keyTab", newKeyTabPath);
prop.store(new java.io.FileOutputStream(loginConfigPath),null);
```

Output of this code:

```
#Tue Jan 21 14:30:24 EST 2020
KafkaClient={
useTicketCache=false
serviceName="kafka"
useKeyTab=true
principal="example.com";
keyTab="C\:/Users/conf/test.keytab"
com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule=required
storeKey=true
};=
```

2 Issues:

1. Colon in keyTab is getting escaped .
2. File output stream is adding additional info like ( = : at the end of the file &&  date on top  of the file) at the end, which is causing it to not work.

I need the format to be

```
KafkaClient {
  com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule required
  useTicketCache=false
  useKeyTab=true
  keyTab="C:/Users/test.keytab"
  serviceName="kafka"
  storeKey=true
  principal="example.com";
};
```

Comment: Why do you need to read the file into a string at all?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a string, just an env-var

For example, running Kafka with a JAAS file [would be done like this](https://docs.confluent.io/current/kafka/authentication_sasl/index.html)

```
set KAFKA_OPTS="-Djava.security.auth.login.config=/path/to/kafka_server_jaas.conf"
bin\windows\kafka-server-start etc\kafka\server.properties
```